# Parametric equation of tangent

Tags: calculus

Find parametric equation for the tangent line at $(1,3,3)$ to the curve of intersection of the surface $z=x^2y$ and

a) the plane $x=1$

b) the plane $y=3$

I found out $\frac{dz}{dx}$ and $\frac{dz}{dy}$ I am stuck at the parametric equation.

Answer (score 0):

$(b)$

$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} = 2xy$

$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}|_{(1,3)} = 6$

$x = 1 + t, y = 3, z = 3 +6t$